# In Wordpress' wp-admin/post.php page, what can I type into the browser console to get the logged in user's display name?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm writing an API that relates to my websites example.com/wp-admin/post.php page and I need the email address (or the part before the @ sign), but I cannot think of a way to access it. I have tried `Object.keys(window)` and `Object.values(window)` and the lists are so large, I've tried traversing it and have found nothing. I've tried wp.autosave.getPostData as well. People login to the admin part of the site with username@example.com.

How can I extract the `username@example.com` in the browser console in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp_get_current_user() will return the current logged in user object in PHP. You need to run the object through json_encode() prior to assigning it to the localized data. Once it is encoded then you can use JSON.parse() in JavaScript which will construct a JS object from the data you pass. The JSON object shall be accessible from the browser console in JavaScript.

You will have access to the following;

user_login
user_email
user_firstname
user_lastname
display_name
ID

Comment: can you not do something similar on the browser side in JS?